# How can I go back to a migration with Flyway?

Tags: oracle, flyway

Let's assume that we have 2 scripts.

One that will create a table (ex: Students) and is named as V1_Students_create.sql and another one named V2_Students_Create.sql that will create a second table (ex: Teachers). After I have migrated to the second version, how can I go back to the first migration (the one where I have executed the first script - V1_Students_create.sql) and have only the first table (Students) created ?

I am using an Oracle database.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot go back or downgrade your migration. There is an issue created for this feature and a lot of discussions are going on that, but still nothing. Here is the link for the issue: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/109